# Sort Excel Pivot Items based on Date

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot-table

Edit: Solved it!! Can't put up solution just yet.

I have a pivottable with a "dates" rowfield. I need a VBA code that sorts from oldest dates to the newest.

I need the dates to be AUS format, ie. dd/mm/yyyy or d mmm yyyy or similar.
This is when Excel does not order them correctly.

So let's say that pivotfield "Dates" has the following pivot items:

```
01 Jan 2012
30 Apr 2012
(blank)
03 Feb 2013
14 Feb 2012
22 Nov 2012
```

The correct order would be:

```
01 Jan 2012
14 Feb 2012
30 Apr 2012
22 Nov 2012
03 Feb 2013
(blank)
```

I think I am getting closer but still no luck.

```
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pfd As PivotField
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set pfd = pt.PivotFields("Snapshot Date")

For Each pi In pfd.PivotItems
pi = CDate(pi) 'converts to US date for sorting 
Next pi

pfd.AutoSort _
xlAscending, "Snapshot Date"

For Each pi In pfd.PivotItems
pi = Format(pi, "d mmm yyyy") 'converts to AUS
Next pi
```

Thanks for your help.
Ramify

Comment: does the cells have the format date? When you click the cell, you should have "01/01/2012" in the formula.

Comment: I have updated description :)

Comment: well, it's better with the code... your function PivotFields returns a range right? Why don't you use sort on it?

Comment: Im trying to sort the pivot items?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to create a macro for that. Select your dates, right click->cell format->date->pick the format you want for your dates.

Then to sort, select all your lines you want to sort, go to data/sort, select the column with your dates and a sorting order (ascending/descending) and click ok.

Your dates should be sorted ;)

EDIT: as you're using a macro, try something like that

```
Set pfd = pt.PivotFields("Snapshot Date")
pfd.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: The problem is I need it to appear as d/mm/yy, not m/dd/yyy. 
If I do a numberformat to the cells, it works, but then it just goes back to US when I refresh. :(

Comment: when you refresh? Are you using a macro to update some other data?

Comment: Does that sort the pivot items or a range ?

Comment: it sorts the range, but I'm not sure about what you really want to do.